# Set up JavaScript to call function with different parameters

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have the following ExtJS controller code:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#menuitem-A': { click: this.handlerA },
        '#menuitem-B': { click: this.handlerB },
    });
},
```

and the following event handlers:

```
commonFunc: function(param1, param2) {
    // do something with param1 and param2 in here
},

handlerA: function(button, event) {
    this.commonFunc('param-A1', 'param-A2');
},

handlerB: function(button, event) {
    this.commonFunc('param-B1', 'param-B2');
},
```

**Problem:** the current code is redundant: `handlerA` and `handlerB` just call `commonFunc` with different parameters

**Question:**
I would like to remove `handlerA` and `handlerB` and instead `call` or `apply` the common function `commonFunc` with the arbitrary parameters within `handlerA` and `handlerB` functions above, for different event handlers. Is it possible?

Example:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#menuitem-A': { click: /*commonFunc with ['param-A1', 'param-A2']*/ },
        '#menuitem-B': { click: /*commonFunc with ['param-B1', 'param-B2']*/ },
    });
},
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about this:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#menuitem-A': { 
            click: function(button, event){
                this.commonFunc('param-A1', 'param-A2');
            }
        },
        '#menuitem-B': { 
            click: function(button, event){
                this.commonFunc('param-B1', 'param-B2');
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: So is it impossible to set up a call to the function (when the event triggers) without actually setting up an intermediate function?

Comment: You could use Ext.Function.bind(), but it's essentially just a shortcut for doing the same thing. The answer provided above is functionally no different from what you had.